# how to set text indices via a variable

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

i'm trying to implement a simple line highlighting mechanism in my tcl/tk *text* widget.

For this I would like to assign all characters marked with one tag to another tag.

as in

```
.window.text insert end "one line\n" line1
.window.text insert end "a chunk spanning\nmultiple lines" line2
.window.text insert end "thats all\n" line3

# get all text that is tagged as 'line2'
set selected [ .window.text tag ranges line2 ]

# and apply the 'highlighed' tag to it:
.window.text tag add highlighted $selected
```

Unfortunately this does notwork, as it gives me

> bad text index "2.0 4.0"

Using the indices literally works fine:

```
.window.text tag add highlighted 2.0 4.0
```

But is not what i want. (I don't know anything about the tagged chunks apart from their tag)

So it seems that I cannot store the list of indices in a variable and use that with `tag add` (or `tag remove` for that matter).

Any hints how I can add a tag to an already tagged text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution (in Tcl 8.5 and later):

```
.window.text tag add highlighted {*}$selected
```

If command A has given you a list of items to feed to command B, but command B expects each item to appear as an argument in its invocation, the list of items needs to be spliced, or *expanded* into separate arguments. In Tcl 8.5, this was facilitated by introducing a new syntactic rule that allowed the number of arguments provided to a command to be increased by expanding one of the existing arguments.

To borrow an example, the `destroy ?window window ...?` command cannot work with the list of windows returned by `winfo children .`, since each window path needs to be a separate argument. Writing

```
destroy [winfo children .]
```

would be evaluated as (say) `destroy {.foo .bar .baz}`, which won't work. However, using the new expansion prefix `{*}`

```
destroy {*}[winfo children .]
```

the line will be evaluated as `destroy .foo .bar .baz`, which will work.

One way to understand it is by thinking of the invocation as a list consisting of the command name and the arguments, and that the `{*}` is an instruction to splice the value of the following argument into that list at that point in the list.

Documentation: [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)